# VBA Excel Ignores PrintArea Pdf

Tags: vba, pdf

I have 250 excel documents where I try to print a sheet for pdf. If I do it manually, it will be 4 pages, but if I use my code, it will be 7 pages long.

It's like it ignores the print area, and makes several blank pages.

Can any of you figure out the mistake?

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim xExtension As String: xExtension = "*.xls*"
    Dim xFolder As String: xFolder = [MailFolder]
    Dim xFile As String: xFile = Dir(xFolder & xExtension) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder
    Dim Rng As Range: Set Rng = Range("A1")
    Dim s As String
    

    
    Do While xFile <> "" 'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
        
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xFolder & xFile): wb.Activate
    
        
        Call WorksheetsToPDF(wb, "F:\VBA\PDF\Udlejning\" & CleanFileName("Police - " & "2021 -" & [KompletPoliceNr] & " - " & [Forsikringstager]) & ".pdf", "Certifikat")
        'Call WorksheetsToPDF(wb, "F:\VBA\KF Begæringer\" & CleanFileName("KF Begæring-2021-" & [KompletPoliceNr] & "-" & [Forsikringstager]) & ".pdf", "Police")
        
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    
    End Sub

Private Sub WorksheetsToPDF(wb As Workbook, DistinationPath As String, ParamArray Arr() As Variant)
    wb.Sheets(Arr()).Select
    Debug.Print EFDK.GetNextavailablefilename(DistinationPath)
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=EFDK.GetNextavailablefilename(DistinationPath), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False

End Sub


Private Function GetNextAvailableFilename(ByVal xPath As String) As String
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim strFolder As String, strBaseName As String, strExt As String, i As Long
        strFolder = .GetParentFolderName(xPath)
        strBaseName = .GetBaseName(xPath)
        strExt = .GetExtensionName(xPath)

        Do While .FileExists(xPath)
            i = i + 1
            xPath = .BuildPath(strFolder, strBaseName & " - " & i & "." & strExt)
        Loop
    End With

    GetNextAvailableFilename = xPath
End Function
```

Comment: Yes exactly - that's also why I do not understand.

Comment: Is `EFDK` a class? Where did you declared it and how? If a class, please edit your question and paste its code.

Comment: It is a module, I have updated the code.

Comment: Are there really empty pages, or the columns exceeding the excel sheet width?

Comment: Still alive? Are there all the extra pages blanc?

Answer (score 0):

You did not answer my clarification questions...

Just for the sake of testing, please try the next adapted function:

```
Private Sub WorksheetsToPDF(wb As Workbook, DistinationPath As String, ParamArray arr() As Variant)
    Dim El
    wb.Sheets(arr()).Select
    For Each El In arr()
       wb.Sheets(El).PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
       wb.Sheets(El).PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4 ' xlPaperLetter
       wb.Sheets(El).PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    Next
    'Debug.Print EFDK.GetNextavailablefilename(DistinationPath)
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=EFDK.GetNextavailablefilename(DistinationPath), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True
End Sub
```